# Changing WSDL of Flex 4.5 Autogenerated Service Proxy Classes

Tags: flash-builder4.5

I used Flash Builder's 4.5 capability to auto generate a proxy class for a given SOAP service.  Everything works fine and dandy, except for the fact that the WSDL url is hardcoded into the auto-generated proxy class.

Now, when I deploy the Flex app onto the production server, I want to change the path of the SOAP service, which will be obtained from a config file.  The internals of the service will be exactly the same.  In the code snippet below, I try to swap wsdl url manually in a subclass of the auto-generated proxy which is Adobe's recommended approach...

```
/**
     * Override super.init() to provide any initialization customization if needed.
     */
    protected override function preInitializeService():void
    {

        super.preInitializeService();
        // Initialization customization goes here

        super.wsdl = "http://s174667r2ycj0l1/mscviewer/MySecretService.asmx?wsdl";
        super.useProxy = false;
    }
```

However, I always get the following error:  "[RPC Fault faultString="You must specify the WSDL location with useProxy set to false." faultCode="Client.WSDL" faultDetail="null"]
at mx.rpc.soap::WebService/loadWSDL()"

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, or if there is a better way to swap wsdl locations?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

- Go to .model folder into your flex project package and open .fml file
- Change the uri for your wsdl

I do that when i want to deploy my fb projects because adobe does not have information about this.

.sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite late, but i stumbled on the same problem today, here is how I solved it :

1. I created a ConfigLoader singleton, in charge of loading configuration via a XML file
2. In my webservice class :

   ```
   import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
   import flash.events.*;

   protected override function preInitializeService():void
   {
      ConfigLoader.instance.addEventListener('config_file_loaded',confLoaded);
      ConfigLoader.instance.load();
   }

   private function confLoaded(e:Event):void
   {
      _serviceControl.service = "bModelo";
      _serviceControl.port = "bModeloSoap";
      wsdl = ConfigLoader.instance.url;
      model_internal::loadWSDLIfNecessary();
   }
   ```